# Visual Studio 2008's annoying auto-handling of block comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I read that great post on Visual Studio 2008 annoyances, but didn't see this one.  It drives me crazy.  Now, I realize that some people use block comments like this for function documentation and the like:

```
/*
 *
 *
 *
 */
```

But you know, this is VS2008 and now we can use ///.  The only time I *ever* feel the need to use C-style commenting is when I have some junk or test code that I temporarily want to remove.  It absolutely drives me nuts when I do the first `/*` and then when I add a line after the test code, it automatically puts a space after the * and I end up with this: `* /` .  So then I end up always having to backspace to complete the block comment.

I looked through all of the C# editor settings in the VS2008 IDE, and didn't find anything relevant.

Does this drive anyone else here crazy, or am I turning into a codemudgeon?

Comment: I think that the fact your on here complaining about a single space being generated, is a sad fact.. If you dont like using block comments. Dont! and if you need to use it, and you end up backspacing once, *Deal with it*

Comment: Goddamn, you are harsh.  I do like to use block comments often, like I said, to comment out test code.

Comment: Do you ever use block comments for any other purpose? I find the extra space really helpful when writing narrative within a block comment - and I use the built in "comment this block of code" function for code instead of block comments. Just my 2c.

Comment: No, I don't. :)  I also use CTRL-E,C CTRL-E,U for commenting blocks w/o a block comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just avoid the block comments and instead I select the block and hit ctrl-k-c which will automatically comment out a whole block with `//` on each line. To undo it select the block and hit ctrl-k-u to uncomment the block. It doesn't fix the extra space issue, but it lets you not care.

Comment: yeah i do that too, but on my system it is ctrl-e,c anf ctrl-e,u for some reason.  :)

Comment: @Dave - Actually I normally use Resharper's version of it, but sometimes I don't have Resharper and revert. Wonder why it's ctrl-k for me.

Answer (score 4):

Without losing XML comments functionality, you can use #if to exclude code frahments, for example:

```
#if EXCLUDED
any code ...
#endif
```

In C++ use #if 0.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior can be turned off, but it will also turn off the automatic creation of XML comments after typing ///.

To turn it off, open the options dialog and go to Text Editor/C#/Advanced.  Uncheck "Generate XML documentation comments for ///".

Comment: thanks...  unfortunately, that won't work for me because I also use /// a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with Dave.  The auto addition of the star on the next comment-block line makes me sad to the point of really disliking Microsoft for imposing their affective and unnecessary formatting standards on the developping community.  Quite honestly, I even find it quite contradictory to most past Microsoft implementations which usually empower the user instead of locking him down in a dark and humid cell.  Hahhh!  The good old times when Bill was king!

Comment: I would have been fine with it all if they just didn't add the space next to the asterisk.  ;)